# How many ServiceMix or Fuse ESB instances on one host

Tags: apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I am new to ServiceMix and want to deploy multiple instances for load balancing reasons. Now I want to know, in practice, how many ServiceMix or FuseESB instances are deployed on a single host like a server?

Is there only one ServiceMix instance for one host? If so, will that instance explore the whole capacity of the host?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy as many instances on the host as you want. They are all just JVM processes.

Though ServiceMix / Fuse ESB allows you to create a child container on the same host, which allows the parent container to manage its child containers. So if you install more instances on the same host, you may want to install them as child containers.

Some docs about child instances can be found here

- http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/users-guide/child-instances.html

Comment: Thanks Claus! ServiceMix is cool and I am trying to use it in our company.